# How do I add more than one dictionary list to a Django return render call?

Tags: python, django

Hey guys I'm trying to send more than one dictionary list to a certain HTML template from Python.  I know how to do it with one list.  How would I send more than one?

In my example below I am sending the list newquery to the render request so that I can use it in my HTML.  But I also want to include another list from my Follows model...what is the correct syntax for this?  Here's what I have:

```
def profile(request, username):
    newquery = Follow.objects.filter(username=username)
    return render(request, "network/profile.html", { "newqueries": newquery })
```

Here's what I want:

```
 def profile(request, username):
        newquery = NewPost.objects.filter(username=username)
        query = Follow.objects.filter(username=username)
        return render(request, "network/profile.html", { "newqueries": newquery }, { "queries": query })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You construct a *single* dictionary with *multiple* records:

```
def profile(request, username):
    newquery = NewPost.objects.filter(username=username)
    query = Follow.objects.filter(username=username)
    return render(
        request,
        'network/profile.html',
        { 'newqueries': newquery, 'queries': query }
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return render(request, "network/profile.html", { "newqueries": newquery }, { "queries": query })
```

can be changed to

```
return render(request, "network/profile.html", { "newqueries": newquery, "queries": query })
```

or

```
return render(request, "network/profile.html", { "allqueries": [newquery, query] })
```